# ActiveRecord scope throwing NoMethod error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following rails model that throws an error when I call the scope.

```
class UserCampaign < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :user_sent_status

scope :todays_campaigns, -> { where("start_date <= ? and complete_date >= ?",Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) }

end
```

When I call

> > UserCampaign.todays_campaigns 
> >     NoMethodError: undefined method `todays_campaigns' for #

How do I set/call this scope?

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems correct. Are you sure you saved both files?

Comment: Thanks Marek. I had to restart my Rails console in order for the changes to be recognised. Once I restarted it, all worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Solution was to restart my rails console that I was using to test the code. once I restarted the console it started working as expected.